# MySQL Group By for sorted table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I've two tables with these structures:

**Table 1 (comments)**

```
+----+---------+------------+--------+---------+
| id | post_id | created_at | author | content |
+----+---------+------------+--------+---------+
|  1 |       3 | 03-01-2020 | Jack   | XXX     |
|  2 |       1 | 02-29-2020 | Joe    | XXX     |
|  3 |       3 | 02-24-2020 | Anna   | XXX     |
|  4 |       2 | 03-01-2020 | Mia    | XXX     |
+----+---------+------------+--------+---------+
```

**Table 2 (posts)**

```
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| id  | category_id |        name         | content |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------+
|   1 |           1 | some random name    | xxxxxxx |
|   2 |           2 | another random name | xxxxxxx |
|   3 |           1 | third random name   | xxxxxxx |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------+
```

My goal is to get a list with the latest comment from each post of a specific `category_id`.

So for example, if I have category 1 as input I need the comments with the id 2 and 1 because these are always the last comments for each post with the given category.

Until now, I got this query which returns all entries ordered by the creation date.

```
select *
from comments c
join posts p on c.post_id = p.id
where p.category_id = 1
order by c.created_at desc;
```

I've read about the `group by` property but this does not guarantee me to get the last entries. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does you need only last created date or all data from relevant table? What about case with several records with same category and equal created time? Also, post what MySQL version you use.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I need only last created date. The case with equal created time should not occur, cause the data is inserted by a cron. I’m using MySQL version 5.7.26

Comment: @Strawberry Is the MCRE good enough?

Comment: The MCRE is non-existent, so 'no'

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. You mean some example data right? If not please explain to me what you mean with MCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Table2` is the *categories* table, if you want in the results only the columns of `Table1` then you don't need a join.
Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.* 
from table_1 t1
where not exists (
  select 1 from table_1
  where table2_id = t1.table2_id and created_at > t1.created_at
)
```

or with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.* 
from table_1 t1
where t1.created_at = (select max(created_at) from table_1 where table2_id = t1.table2_id)
```

Edit:

```
select c.*
from posts p inner join (
  select c.* from comments c
  where not exists (
    select 1 from comments
    where post_id = c.post_id and created_at > c.created_at
  )
) c on c.post_id = p.id
where p.category_id = ?
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koPstzb46Vsz1miR9nUWvU/0).
Or:

```
select c.*
from posts p inner join (
  select c.* from comments c
  where c.post_id in (select id from posts where category_id = ?)
  and not exists (
    select 1 from comments
    where post_id = c.post_id and created_at > c.created_at
  )
) c on c.post_id = p.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/koPstzb46Vsz1miR9nUWvU/1).
Replace `?` with the `category_id` you want to search for.
Results:

```
| id  | post_id | created_at          | author | content |
| --- | ------- | ------------------- | ------ | ------- |
| 1   | 3       | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | Jack   | XXX     |
| 2   | 1       | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | Joe    | XXX     |
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I've updated the post with a more practical example. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Thank you very much. The query is a little bit more complex as excepted :D

Comment: PS. is it possible to add an additional where filter to the results of the comments? For example when I want the only comment's from Author Joe or I have an additional active flag?

Comment: You can add as many conditions as you want inside the joined query in the WHERE clause, but for each new condition you should add also the same condition in the subquery of NOT EXISTS.

Comment: But this filter's the whole result, right? I updated your demo and instead of the last comment's matching the filter it doesn't return any comment if the filter not match to the last https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x9uFYwJvBhvBKAWH44xrmG/1

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x9uFYwJvBhvBKAWH44xrmG/2

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` with aggregate function `MAX` should to resolve your problem:

```
SELECT 
  b.id AS category_id, 
  MAX(a.created_at) AS last_created
FROM table_1 a
JOIN table_2 b on a.table2_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY last_created DESC;
```